# What is Isabella holding in her hand when she gets anime-fied?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

In the *Phineas and Ferb* special episode "Summer Belongs to You", during their brief stopover in Tokyo, the crew gets anime-fied temporarily.

This includes Isabella for a moment:

[image: Isabella]

What is that green thing she's holding in her hand here? I didn't see her holding anything before, so what's she holding here?

Answer (score 10):

Going down the rabbit-hole of the [Phineas and Ferb wikia](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/J-Pop_(Welcome_to_Tokyo)), the song is inspired by **Ievan Polkka**

> The anime-inspired dance sequence in Tokyo parodies two popular internet memes, one which involves various animated characters dancing to a sped-up remix of the Swedish pop song Caramelldansen, and another which uses the Finnish song **Ievan Polkka** called "**Loituma Girl**" **(aka "Leekspin")**. Although Isabella was animated doing the Vocaloid version which involves an up-and-down movement rather than twirling.

And that led to the [wikia article with the song name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ievan_Polkka) which in turn led to:

**[Loituma Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loituma_Girl)**

[image: Leek Girl GIF]

Thus to answer your question, Isabella is holding a **leek**.